# Scan folders and load files from folder

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion, array-merge

I have a folder structure:

```
- components
--com_name
---routes
----routes.json
--com_another_name
---routes
----routes.json
...
--com_x
---routes
----routes.json
```

How can I load every routes.json file from each com_x folder and merge to one array?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iterators, like below. Recursively looking for json files:

```
$path = realpath($pathToYourMainDir);

$directoryIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));
$regexIterator = new RegexIterator($directoryIterator, '#^(?:[A-Z]:)?(?:/(?!\.Trash)[^/]+)+/[^/]+\.(?:json)$#Di');
$files = [];

foreach ($regexIterator as $file) {
    array_push($files, $file->getPathName());
}
```

$files contain the json file names (including the path).